# ¿Porque al imprimir el bucle for me da asi?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy empezando con esto de la programación y apenas empecé a ver el bucle for.

No me queda claro lo siguiente:

Porque cuando imprimo "i", se me almacena el ultimo valor de mi lista?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por ayudarme. No me queda claro eso.

Comment: por que `i` toma cada valor de la lista y al imprimirlo fuera del ciclo este se queda con el ultimo valor

Comment: Como sugerencia, coloca el código como texto, las preguntas con imágenes mostrando código no son bien recibidas

Answer (score 2):

Cuando un ciclo `for` termina, la variable de control queda con el último valor asignado dentro del ciclo.

Esto es válido si el `for` termina normalmente o si se sale vía `break`.

En este código con termino normal, el último valor usado dentro del ciclo es `9`:

```
for i in range(10):
    pass
print(i)
```

En este otro, en que se sale vía `break` cuando `n == 5`, la variable de control queda en 5 (lógico):

```
for n in range(10):
    if n == 5:
        break

print(n) => Imprime 5
```